# How do I setup a Raspberry Pi zero w as a Wi-Fi client (internal Wi-Fi) and access point (USB adapter) simultaneously?

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, access-point

I followed the tutorial, [Raspberry Pi Wireless Access Point](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wireless-access-point/), to set my Raspberry Pi Zero as an access point.

I do have an additional USB adapter connected. The pi that I’m working on will be an on board computer for a drone. The built in wifi will connect to my wifi at home to run updates browse logs and the like. The USB adapter will host the access point and will connect to a controller through a very directional antenna.

When I finished and rebooted the USB adapter connected to the same Wi-Fi network that the internal Wi-Fi connects to.

I know that I’ve got to be missing some detail somewhere but I’m not sure what steps to take first to troubleshoot this problem.

**Edit**

After following the tutorial listed in the comments this is returned from `iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Zimm_Wrls"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 48:5D:36:D3:C4:7C   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**Upadate 20180705:**

I ran lsusb to see what driver I should be using in case that was part of the issue. This is what was returned:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

This is /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=rt1871xdrv
ssid=BigBird
hw_mode=g
channel=6
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=ninarubysue
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

and then this:

```
bigbird:~/rt8192cu $ sudo hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 1: invalid line '$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Line 3: invalid/unknown driver 'rt1871xdrv'
2 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interface
```

Comment: You might have more luck with the Foundation tutorial https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: ASAIK, it's not possible to do both things **at the same time** with with a single wireless device. Do you have 2 wireless devices on the rpi? Perhaps the internal one and a USB-dongle?

Comment: @eftshift0 It is possible. There are many articles on the web how to do that. *@Milliways* has pointed to the official.

Comment: @Loren_Zimmer Do you have two wifi devices on your raspi, a wifi usb dongle and a build in wifi device (means you have a *pi zero W*)?

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Loren_Zimmer I don't read the tutorial you have linked to but as far as I see it doesn't use two wifi devices. So your setup with two wifi devices following this tutorial cannot work. Do you really want to use two devices? It is a bit more flexible.

Comment: Sorry, yes I do have a pi zero w with a USB adapter connected.  I’ve added what the results after following the Foundation tutorial

Comment: Are you bridging two different wifi networks? I've always wondered how this use case arises.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics the pi that I’m working on will be an on board computer for a drone.  The built in wifi will connect to my wifi at home to run updates browse logs and the like.  The USB adapter will host the access point and will connect to a controller through a very directional antenna.

Comment: To qualify: it should work as the USB wifi adapter should show as separate interface ([known working ones here](https://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)), all you should need to do is swap `eth0` for `wlan1` (IF `wlan0` is the hotspot) in Milliways linked tutorial, with `wlan1` setup normally as the active network connection (instead of `eth0`). The only problem is if the `wlan`'s assigned numbers swap around on boot (reboot a few times to check) AND the assigned drivers get swapped & don't work. Also lookup stuff like https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-extender/

Comment: @LorenZimmer You wrote: *"the access point will connect to a controller*". Just to clarify: an ap cannot connect to other devices. You mean, "the controller will connect to the ap", right? As far as I understand you want to have an access point the controller can connect to and you want the rpi0w to connect to your remote home access point as wifi client for updates. Is it that? For this you don't need an extra USB dongle.

Comment: @Ingo you are right, I wrote when I was fairly tired.  I understand that the controller will connect to the AP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I originally started this process I had the adapter plugged in.  I reinstalled the OS and then went through the entire Foundation Tutorial process without the adapter connected.  I ran into some errors due to added spaces in the config files but once I fixed the errors and connected the USB adapter it works like it should.

Thanks to everyone for the comments and helpful tips!

Loren

Answer (score 1):

Your setup cannot work because you are following a tutorial that configures only one wifi device, a wifi USB adapter **or** the wifi on board chip. This single device is configured to work as an access point. The traffic from its connected clients is routed to the ethernet port. So we have a wireless lan connected to a wired lan.

You use two different wifi devices so you try to work with two wireless lans. This does not match the conditions of the tutorial. You should look for an appropriate tutorial.

Comment: Correct. without modification to the tutorial

Comment: @Wilf I'm not sure if you just can replace `eth0` with `wlan0` in the tutorial. I don't believe it but haven't yet tested it.

Comment: I haven't either and can't test for a week, but I'm sure it should. the wifi should be on different channels (this is usually assigned automatically) so they don't interfere with each other as much

Comment: @Wilf *hostapd* must have a channel in its conf file. *wpa_supplicant* (for wlan0) connects to the channel the remote ap offers; may conflict ...

Comment: @Ingo do you have an example of an appropriate tutorial?

Comment: @LorenZimmer I will update my answer to match your needs. But I'm just writing on another answer. Just a moment please ...